# mongodb no such file or directory wiredtiger_kv_engine

Tags: mongodb

what I did : 
went to the database directory and

```
mongod --dbpath .
```

then I got this:

```
2017-02-16T23:51:51.965+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=31656 port=27017 dbpath=. 64-bit host=WIN-01604161705
2017-02-16T23:51:51.966+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2017-02-16T23:51:51.968+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.1
2017-02-16T23:51:51.969+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 5e103c4f5583e2566a45d740225dc250baacfbd7
2017-02-16T23:51:51.970+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t-fips  3 May 2016
2017-02-16T23:51:51.971+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-02-16T23:51:51.972+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-02-16T23:51:51.973+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-02-16T23:51:51.974+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
2017-02-16T23:51:51.975+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-02-16T23:51:51.975+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-02-16T23:51:51.978+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "." } }
2017-02-16T23:51:51.982+0800 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in . created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2017-02-16T23:51:51.982+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3519M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-02-16T23:51:51.992+0800 I -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:2: No such file or directory src\mongo\db\storage\wiredtiger\wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 267
2017-02-16T23:51:51.992+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28595 2: No such file or directory, terminating
2017-02-16T23:51:51.993+0800 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-02-16T23:51:51.994+0800 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-02-16T23:51:51.996+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-02-16T23:51:51.998+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

I don't know what's going on at all.
all that I have done is just common things like revising my files in other directories, **merge** the branch 'master' into 'b2' **using github client**.
I doubt that something went wrong when I did the 'merge' operation.
I have tried using **git revert** to make it roll back, still getting the same error.
Should I reinstall mongodb? I'm doing so.